# $.POST method variable assignment

Tags: jquery

First timer on using this method. I don't know why it doesn't return the specified return value. Can anyone help me to correct my code so I could get a return value of true/false in the statement below:

```
$.post('php/username_check.php',{ username: uname, password: upass }, function(data){
            if(data == 1) {
                $('#result').html("Login successful!");
                return true;

            } else {
                $('#result').html('<div style="color:red;border:1px solid red;padding:5px;">Username and password invalid.</div>');
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but it does not make sense to have statement after the `return` as these will never be executed.

Comment: Your html() functions are never executed, move both _return_ below their respective _$('#result')_ calls...

Comment: Who's supposed to see those return values?  They are being returned by the anonymous function that is the callback handler for the post request. They aren't accessible to anyone.

Comment: $.post method returns an jqXHR (Promise). You can read more about it [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: My apology for the wrong coding. What I want to happen here is, if the  "username_check.php" returns a value of 1 it will open the next page. Else, stay as is. I used this code in my Login page. Is there any other way to do this? Please post your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX is Asynchronous**

Just remember that the callback function doesn't execute immediately, but will (possibly) be invoked at some point in the future when the result comes back. This means you can put your "result" logic in that function, or other functions that are called by that function... for instance:

```
function handleResult(success) {
  if(success /* === 1*/) {
    $('#result').html("Login successful!");
  }
  else {
    $('#result').html('<div style="color:red;border:1px solid red;padding:5px;">Username and password invalid.</div>');
  }
}

$.post('php/username_check.php', {username: uname, password: upass}, handleResult);
```

**jQuery.post**

The [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method is a shortcut for the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method which returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object.

It does not return the values returned from the callback functions provided to the post method.

> As of jQuery 1.5, the $.ajax() method returns the jqXHR object, which
>   is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. For more information, see
>   the jqXHR section of the $.ajax entry

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) for more info on the jqXHR object.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery to POST your data to a specified URL. The function (as argument) passed to `$.post` is a callback function.

Since it is an AJAX request, normally it is asynchronous (unless you specifies it is synchronous.) Therefore, your javascript will not wait for the response of `$.post`. It will keep running to the next statment. For example, if your code like this:

```
function() {
  $.post(......../* your coding */);

  console.log('XXXXXXXXX');
}
```

The above function will process `$.post` and `console.log` nearly at the same time. After `console.log` is complete, the function ends.

While response is received from `$.post`, jQuery will then call your callback function to proceed your logic.